# kubernetes deploy Pod and python file start

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, kubernetes-deployment

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: testserver
    image: test_server:2.5
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
      - containerPort: 5100
    env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
    volumeMounts:
      - name: testserver
        mountPath: /app/test/csv
#    command: ["/bin/bash"]
#    args: ["-c", "python /app/api/Python_Rest.py"]

  - name: testdb
    image: lev_test_db:1.4
    ports:
      - containerPort: 1433
    env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
    volumeMounts:
      - name: testdb
        mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data

  volumes:
  - name: testserver
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/testhostpath/testserver
  - name: levmldb
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/testhostpath/testdb
```

If you do it in the way I commented out, tomcat does not work properly because the python server is running before tomcat succeeds.

Deploy tomcat conatiner using yaml file in kubernetes environment, and if tomcat succeeds normally, I want to run python file. What should I do?

Comment: First thought: Add a sleep command before the python start... Maybe there is a more sophisticated possibility of making python *wait* for tomcat to start.

Comment: You'd generally run these in two separate Deployments; then the Python Pod can exit and restart until the Tomcat Pod is up and running.  You should also consider some other storage besides `hostPath` volumes, which can become misplaced as Pods get scheduled on different nodes.

Comment: python and tomcat share a physical directory, they are trying to run in the same pod.
thank you fort answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use the sleep command to delay the testserver start
A little more fancy solution can be

```
command:
  - "sleep"
  - "100"
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: 
        - "sh"
        - "-c"
        - |
          python /app/api/Python_Rest.py
```

Comment: I tried, but I got an Error.
 command: 
#    args: ["-c", "python /app/levml/api/test_Rest.py"]
#    args: ["-c", "nohup python /app/levml/api/test_Rest.py&"]
      - sleep
      - 100
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
            - "sh"
            - "-c"
            - |
              "python /app/api/test_Rest.py"

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you still see the same error?